# Residue Theorem for Trig Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I am trying to use the Residue Theorem to calculate the following integral:
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\rm d}\theta \frac{\cos^{2}\left(\theta\right)}{\cos^{2}\left(\theta\right) + k^{2}\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)}\quad\mbox{where}\quad k \leq 1
$$
Making the substitution $z = {\rm e}^{{\rm i}\theta}$, I get:

\begin{align}
I & = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{\left\vert z\right\vert\ =\ 1}\,\,\,
\frac{\left(z^{2} + 1\right)^{2}/\left(4z^2\right)}{-k^2(z-1)^2(z+1)^2/(4z^2) +(z^2+1)^2/(4z^2)}
\\[3mm] & = \int \frac{(z-i)^2(z+i)^2}{-k^2(z-1)^2(z+1)^2 + (z-i)^2(z+i)^2}
\end{align}

I am not quite sure what to do from here. Plugging the denominator into WolframAlpha gives $\displaystyle z = \pm \frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{\sqrt{k-1}}$, z =0, and $ z = \pm \frac{\sqrt{k-1}}{\sqrt{k+1}}$. Do I compute the residues at all 5 of these poles and add them? Also, how do we consider the case where k=1 for these poles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the residues from the poles inside your contour contribute to your integral (by Cauchy's residue theorem.)  And your contour is the unit circle in the plane.  So if you look at the magnitudes of your poles, you'll find that only three of them actually lie inside your contour.

As far as the $k \to 1$ limit, note that in this case the integral reduces to $\int_0^{2 \pi} \cos^2 \theta \, d \theta$.  I suppose that you could evaluate this integral with the residue theorem but it seems like overkill.